# When the carousel ends show button next to it

Tags: flutter

When the user is done browsing the 4 images in the carousel i want to show a see more button like the image below.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3haM.jpg)

I've tried adding another carousel slide and only putting the button in it but it looks like a card and it dosen't looks right i just need a little bit of space and this button to apear.

This is the carousel:

```
CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: 200.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
            autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            viewportFraction: 0.8,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
          items: cardList.map((card) {
            return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: card,
                ),
              );
            });
          }).toList(),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();

  final List list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

  bool showNext = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          children: [
            CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                carouselController: buttonCarouselController,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  height: 200,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                  viewportFraction: 0.8,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    if(list[index] == list.last){
                      setState(() {
                        showNext = true;
                      });
                    }else{
                      if(showNext){
                        setState(() {
                          showNext = false;
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(list[itemIndex]),
                  );
                }
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: showNext,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  buttonCarouselController.jumpToPage(0);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,size: 30,),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Pic]